# How to get time when android activity started?

Tags: android, time, android-activity

I need to get the time stamp when activity is started.and also the the current time when an activity is running.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why not writing the current time to a Date field in the `onCreate` method? You get the current time via `System.currentTimeMillis()`.